# How do you restart the download manager service?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, download-manager

I was using my Nexus 7 (android 4.2.2) through the hotspot on my phone and the download manager was trying to download a large app update. I pressed and held the notification to get to the app info for download manager and disabled it. How do I re-enable it?

Comment: Have you tried going to *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps* and see if you can find the Download Manager there? Might either be in the alphabetic order, or moved to the end of the list. Tap its entry, tap the "enable" button.

Comment: It should be under Settings -> Apps -> All at the bottom of the list (if you have multiple apps disabled, it will be sorted alphabetically below all the enabled apps). Just click on it and click the enable button.

Comment: Thanks guys. Why don't you post an answer then I can accept it rather than a comment.

Comment: How come you didn't accept @Al E. answer? You had the information you needed, plus it credited the commenters.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Apps then scroll to the right.

You'll see a few tabs:

1. Downloaded
2. Running,
3. All
4. Disabled (if any of your apps are disabled)

In the Disabled tab find the Download Manager and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Izzy says:

> Have you tried going to *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps* and see if you can find the Download Manager there? Might either be in the alphabetic order, or moved to the end of the list. Tap its entry, tap the "enable" button.

bassmadrigal says:

> It should be under Settings -> Apps -> All at the bottom of the list (if you have multiple apps disabled, it will be sorted alphabetically below all the enabled apps). Just click on it and click the enable button.